# How to use variable's in different method?

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm writing a program in C#,console Application and I bumped into a problem.

So far I've got five class's: the main class which is `Program` and four other `Teacher`, `Student`, `Course`, `Class`.

My problem is that I receive the information from user and the info's are all in another method.

I want to be able to use the input that I get from the user and use it in different method to edit the input.

Simply saying the program should be able to edit the input's and I can't make it work?!?
and this is the code that I wrote:

```
struct Students
{
   public string name;
   public string family;
   public int ID;
   public string Major;
   public int studentCode;
} 

class Student
{
    public static void ShowStudent() 
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("This is Student's Section:\n");
        Console.WriteLine("====================================");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Number Of the Section you want to Work with:\n");
        Console.WriteLine("1 Submit");
        Console.WriteLine("2 Edit");
        Console.WriteLine("3 Back");
        string choice = Console.ReadLine();

        switch (choice)
        {
            case "1":
                ReciveStudent();
                break;
            case "2":
                break;
            case "3":
                Program.mainShow();
                break;
            default:
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter INrange Number.\nPress any Key to Continue....");
                Console.ReadKey();
                ShowStudent();
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void ReceiveStudent()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        int n;

        Console.WriteLine("How Many Student's you Want to Enter?");
        n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Students[]  st = new Students[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student ID:");
            st[i].ID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student CODE:");
            st[i].studentCode = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Name:");
            st[i].name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Family:");
            st[i].family = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Major:");
            st[i].Major = Console.ReadLine();                         
        }

        ShowStudent();
    }
}
```

The `ShowStudent()` method is called in the main, which is the `program.cs` (`void main`).

I want to use the array values in different method.

Appreciate any comment...

Thanks guys.

Comment: Have you considered returning the `st` array from `Receive` method and storing it inside the main method for future uses?

Comment: @EugenePodskal Are you sure it works???
cause i think when the receiving is done the value would be changed to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the data that the method RecieveStudent collects from the user and use the data as input to another method.

Change RecieveStudent to: `public static Students[] RecieveStudent()`

```
public static Students[] RecieveStudent() {
    // your code here as is
    return st;
}
```

And use the returned array as input to other methods:

```
Students[] students = ReceiveStudent();
otherMethod(students) // Do other work on data
```

Btw, your naming could use some work. E.g. your struct Students does't actually model a group of students, but only one.

EDIT:

```
struct Students
{
   public string name;
   public string family;
   public int ID;
   public string Major;
   public int studentCode;
} 

class Student
{
    public static void ShowStudent() 
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("This is Student's Section:\n");
        Console.WriteLine("====================================");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Number Of the Section you want to Work with:\n");
        Console.WriteLine("1 Submit");
        Console.WriteLine("2 Edit");
        Console.WriteLine("3 Back");
        string choice = Console.ReadLine();
        Students[] students = null;

        switch (choice)
        {
            case "1":
                students = ReciveStudent();
                break;
            case "2":
                break;
            case "3":
                Program.mainShow();
                break;
            default:
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter INrange Number.\nPress any Key to Continue....");
                Console.ReadKey();
                ShowStudent();
                break;
        }

        // Use variable 'students' here
        // Remember to check for null as it might not have been mutated in the switch-case.
        if (students != null)
        {
            // Do something with students here... just printing it for now.
            Console.WriteLine(students.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static Students[] ReceiveStudent()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        int n;

        Console.WriteLine("How Many Student's you Want to Enter?");
        n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Students[]  st = new Students[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student ID:");
            st[i].ID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student CODE:");
            st[i].studentCode = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Name:");
            st[i].name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Family:");
            st[i].family = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Major:");
            st[i].Major = Console.ReadLine();                         
        }

        ShowStudent();

        return st;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the solution...
I just started this and you can say it's kind of in the prototype mode.

Comment: Np :) consider accepting it, if it answers your question

Comment: Though a static class array will work, this is a bad practice. Then again, the proper solution would consist of a console application that would keep track of a StudentCollection, a Student class where instances could display themselves, and a StudentEditor object that could enter new Students or edit existing ones. But apparently, that is overkill.

Comment: @ssnielsen if you could be a little more specific about how I can put them in a variable, that would be perfect.

Comment: @ssnielsen why did you check it for null(Students[] students = null;) and how I can use the previous value when you put the null in the reference?!?

Comment: I didn't check it for null. You should before you access the variable as the method might not be called (i.e. the user picks one of the other cases in the switch statement. Answer update in a second...